# Custom checkbox and custom button

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I use Visual Studio 2010 and program in C#.
I realized a custom checkbox and a custom button in a panel of a Windows Form.
I wish to click my button and verify all the elements checked into the custom checkbox but I don't know how I can do.
Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the elements checked into the custom checkbox"? Do you have one checkbox or many? Can you share the code you already tried?

Comment: You should update to Visual Studio 2017. Did you attach an event handler? Show your code behind code.

Comment: show the code taht you have so far (at least parts related to the question). what exactly should happen when the button is clicked?